# What are the three sources that are relayed to the brakes and steering control unit of an A320?

Tags: airbus-a320, landing-gear, braking

**There is the sentence:**

> Electrical signals from the three sources are relayed to the brakes and steering control unit (BSCU) and are computed into the nose steering angle.

**The question:** What are these sources and where they located?

Comment: Where have you extracted this sentence from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where your text is from, but the 3 sources are:

> The BSCU receives orders from:
>
> ‐ The Captain's and the First Officer’s steering hand wheels (orders added algebraically),
>   ‐ The rudder pedals,
>   ‐ The autopilot.
>
> The BSCU transforms these orders into nose wheel steering angle.

(A320 FCOM DSC-32-20-10)